# Grails relating values from two different domains in a custom view

Tags: grails

While I'm experienced with Java, I am a Grails newbie but I am trying to get into it.  I set up a basic "School" application containing the following domains:

- Student
- Class
- Attendance

Both the 'Student' and 'Class' domains are scaffolded.  Now, I want to create the 'Attendance' domain, and I'm going to need a controller with a custom view. I can do that, I'm just looking to understand (at a high level) the best way to set up the view (let's call it 'attendance.gsp').

The view will contain a dropdown box to select a class. Once a class is selected, I want to populate a table. The first column will contain the list of students in the class, and the second column will contain "Attended?" checkboxes.

I think that I can at least get that far.

I am wondering how to go about relating the checkbox value to the student. Since this class is not scaffolded, no attendance column has been created in the database. Do I need to have anything defined in the Attendance domain? How might you go about doing this? Can anyone recommend a particular example online that is doing something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class Class {
    ...
    static hasMany = [sessionsAttendance: Attendance]
}

class Student {
    ....
}

class Attendance {
    static hasMany = [studentsAttended: Student]
}
```

Comment: Hi 16dots, can you explain this a bit more? I tried adding this, and the only changes that I see are a studentsAttended dropdown box when creating a new Attendance and a sessionsAttendance dropdown box when creating a new Class. What I'm looking to do is to be able to view all students registered to a selected class, and then update their attendance. Thanks!